# Surface with $\nabla F=(0,0,0)$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In my geometry book there is a Proposition that says that: Lets M={ (x,y,z) | F(x,y,z)=0} be a $R^3$ set, and $p=(x_0, y_0, x_0)\in M$. If $\nabla F(p) \neq(0,0,0)\; \forall p \in M$ then M is a surface.
If the book says that "if" instead of "if and only if", I assume that if $\nabla F(p)=(0,0,0)$ for some $p\in M$ I can't say that M is not a surface, so I assume that there exists some surfaces with $\nabla F(p)=(0,0,0)$.

Could someone show me an example of a surface with $\nabla F(p)=(0,0,0)$ if it exists?

PS: I know that $\nabla F(p)=(0,0,0)$ is equivalent to N(p)=(0,0,0) where N(p) is the normal vector of M in p.

Comment: Your PS is not accurate. One should not ever say that the zero vector is a normal vector of anything. The geometric relation between vectors that they be "perpendicular" is only defined when the two vectors are nonzero.

Comment: True, I wanted to say that $\nabla F(p)=k*N(p)$ where $k \in R$ so there is a relation between $\nabla F(p)$ and N(p)

Answer (score 3):

It holds, obviously, $\{(x,y,z)\ |\ F(x,y,z)=0\}=\{(x,y,z)\ |\ F^2(x,y,z)=0\}$

But $\nabla(F^2)(p)=2F(p)\nabla F(p)\equiv 0$ on $\{(x,y,z)\ |\ F(x,y,z)=0\}$.

So any surface as in your first hypothesis is ALSO the set of zeros of a function with null gradient on the whole surface.

Comment: Very nice generalization.  ***Plus One!!!***

Comment: Ok, let me do the question in a different way. Lets M be a surface defined by the chart $(U, \phi(u, v))$ and $p=\phi (u_0, v_0) \in M$ lets N(p) be the normal vector of M ( where $N(p)=\frac{\phi_u(u_0, v_0) \times \phi_v (u_0, v_0)}{||\phi_u(u_0, v_0) \times \phi_v(u_0, v_0)||}$). Is there a surface that N(p)=(0,0,0) in some $p \in M$

Comment: The definition I know of "surface" (embedded $C^1$ 2-manifold) from the last course in Differential Geometry I attended required a chart to have maximum rank (making your suggestion trivially false), so I need to know yours. @will198

Comment: Mine is the same, and now I realice that there is no surface with N(p)=0!!!.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function

$F(x, y, z) = z^2 \tag{1}$

on $\Bbb R^3$.  Then

$\nabla F(x, y, z) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 2z \end{pmatrix} = 0; \tag{2}$

on the $x$-$y$ plane:  $\nabla F = 0$ precisely when $z = 0$.  The $x$-$y$ plane is certainly a surface, even though $\nabla F$ vanishes there.